# Division, multiplication, addition and subtraction of significant figures

Tags: significant-figures

$1.$After adding two or more numbers, the number of digits after the decimal in the result=Least no. of digits after the decimal in the numbers being added.

$2.$After multilplying two numbers, no. of significant figures in a result= no. of significant figures in a number with least no. of significant figures, out of the numbers operated.

Why these two rules are made? How they help us? Why only these, not something else?

Comment: This is a basic question, and not really about chemistry. However, a quick internet search shows that most treatments of significant figures are in introductory chemistry textbooks, and mostly they don't explain the ideas behind the rules. Thus, I think it is a valid question.

Comment: Everything you want on the topic is right here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty . Lots of links to explore. Bottom line: the simplest significant figures rules given in undergrad textbooks, and others of that ilk, do an OK job for most purposes, but they are not definitive.

Comment: But all the things mentioned there in wikipedia are really complex. I was unable to get anything it has.

Comment: There is also a much simpler wikipedia article: search for “Significant figures” in wikipedia. Bottom line: significant figures rules are just useful rules of thumb. They are attempts to use a single number to convey both a “best estimate” and its uncertainty. This is not really possible, but the simple significant figures rules do an OK job of approximating what is actually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why these two rules are made?

These rules are approximations of more sophisticated error propagation treatment. For addition and subtraction, for example, if the first number is a ± 0.1 and the second is b ± 0.001, and the numbers are independent of each other and normally distributed, the absolute error of the sum is $$\sqrt{0.1^2 + 0.001^2}.$$ That comes out to just about 0.1. On the other hand, if both have a uncertainty of ±0.1, the uncertainty of the sum is actually a bit higher, approximately ±0.14.

If you want to get a feel for error propagation, you can always try out the highest and lowest estimate for your numbers (e.g. for 14.2 ± 0.1 that would be 14.3 and 14.1) and plug them into your calculation. If you are calculating with two numbers, you get four combinations, all with different answers. The spread in those answers gives you an idea of how the errors propagate. This is especially useful if you need to take a logarithm or raise something to a power because most textbooks leave out the rules for those.

> How they help us?

They save use some time compared to the more rigorous error propagation treatment. This comes at the expense of sometimes writing too many digits, or losing some information by writing too few.

> Why only these, not something else?

There are lots of other options. My favorite for introductory labs is to say use four significant figures in intermediate calculations, and three significant figures for results. Typically, there is a source of error larger than 1% somewhere in the experiment, so there is no loss of data. On the other hand, writing down three significant figures is not too onerous, and does not use up too much space.

Comment: How you got the formula for absolute error of the sum?

Comment: Let me consider 14.2+2.3=(14.1+2.1)=16.2 or 14.2+2.3=(14.3+2.4)=16.6. Here, absolute error is 0.2, not equal to 0.14, as mentioned by you. Please spot the mistake here.

Comment: What you are doing is the sum of the errors rather than the *quadratic* sum of the errors. The latter is based on the fact that the variance (which is the square of the standard deviation) of a sum or difference is the sum of the variances. So, first square 0.1, then add it to itself (for the second equal error), then take the square root of the sum. This is the quadratic sum and it is 0.1 times the square root of 2. If you just sum 0.1 and 0.1, you get the ordinary sum, which is 0.2. Both Karsten and @Poutnik (his second equation) correctly show the quadratic sum being used.

Comment: Your calculation is a worst-case scenario. In many case errors go in opposite direction and cancel out partially. The derivation of the square root formula involves a double integral over the two Gaussian distributions of actual values, so it would warrant a separate question.

Comment: If you want to follow all the math, then you need to learn about expectation values and then this heavily upvoted link is excellent: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31181/247352 . But it is way easier to just go with the simplified rules of thumb! One last thing: the variance of a sum is the sum of variances only if the two random variables are uncorrelated, which we are tacitly assuming here.

Comment: As mentioned by you that 0.2 uncertainty after the sum is a worst case scenario. You mean that the sum could have atmost 0.2 error, no more than this. Then why we take it to be 0.14, since it could be more or less than this?? Please note that i am unknown to the topics like variance, deviation, etc. BUT then too, i think that the sum should contain max. of 0.2 uncertainty.Then why it makes sense for us to take it equal to 0.14 as in actual it could be more or less than this.

Answer (score 0):

Significant figures were made to aid us in rounding to an appropriate number. We can only base our rounding on the least significant out of given values; or else we aren't guaranteed an accurate result.

For example, in Olympic swimming, there are often lots of ties. Modern technology could definitely track down to thousandths of a second or below, but since the pool's tolerance (and therefore its length for a given lane) fluctuates, there is statistically no way to know that the "winner" didn't have a shorter length to swim. As such, we can only make our time as significant as we know the length of the pool.

Comment: Here is an article about why swimming contests currently use 0.01 seconds as the shortest time interval: https://deadspin.com/this-is-why-there-are-so-many-ties-in-swimming-1785234795

Answer (score 0):

If quantities are added or subtracted:

Their **absolute** maximal errors are additive.

$$e_{A+B}=e_{A}+e_{B}$$

The squares of their **absolute**  mean errors ( like standard deviation or confidence intervals ) are additive.

$$(\sigma_{A+B})^2=(\sigma_{A})^2+(\sigma_{B})^2$$

If quantities are multiplied or divided:

Their **relative** maximal errors are additive.

$$e_{\mathrm{rel},A+B}=e_{\mathrm{rel},A}+e_{\mathrm{rel},B}$$

The squares of their  **relative** mean errors are additive.

$$(\sigma_{ \mathrm{rel}, A+B})^2=(\sigma_{ \mathrm{rel}, A})^2+(\sigma_{  \mathrm{rel},B})^2$$

---

As consequence, if **simplified** :

For the addition/subtraction case, absolute errors are significant.

Therefore the last valid digit  **position** of the most errorneous  quantity matters.

$$(1.0\pm 0.1) + (2.00\pm 0.01) = (3.0\pm 0.1)$$

For the multiplication/division case, relative errors are significant.

Therefore the **number** of valid  positions of the most errorneous  quantity matters.

$$(1.0\pm 0.1) * (200\pm 1) = (200\pm 20)$$

Comment: Let me consider 14.2+2.3=(14.1+2.1)=16.2 or 14.2+2.3=(14.3+2.4)=16.6. Here, absolute error is 0.2, which comes out to be 0.14 according to your formula. Why not 0.2?? ( I had no idea about standard deviation or something like that. But got some idea from karsten Theis' answer. It says that in addition of above mentioned numbers, there is an error propagation of 0.14, but not 0.2, which should be, as per me.)

Comment: As was said, positions and valid digit numbers are simplifications. Absolute maximum error or absolute mean error ? Your example has errors in its errors. Get them right. Btw, the formulas are not mine, they are well known formulas of maximum and mean error propagation.

Comment: if there is (14.2 +- 0.2 ) + ( 5.6+-0.1)=(19.7+-0.3), it is for maximum absolute error 0.2+0.1=0.3.